# Split GA4 conversions by corresponding event

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-4

I'm tracking several events on my website using Google Analytics 4.

Some of those events are more important and I'm considering them as conversions. However, they happen at different steps of the user journey, so each of them would have a different cost and return, so I'd like to consider them as different conversions, in the same way they correspond to different events.

The problem is, when I want to report on them (e.g. on Data Studio, or Google Ads UI, or even on Google Analytics funnels), you can only see the aggregated sum of conversions, rater than being able to select a specific conversion.

Is there a way to make GA4 (an Data Studio) either:

1. Split reports by specific conversions (rather than the total number of conversions)?
2. Split reports by events rather than conversions?

I feel like GA4 has been a step back in terms of report customisation and data analysis.

Thanks!